# How to present articles & videos in the same section

Tags: website-design, interaction-design, navigation, content

This might seem really obvious but i'm working on a cookery site and under the tab 'How to cook' there will be videos to show you this as well as step-by-step articles the user can print. 
Within this 'How to cook' section, there are further categories too (e.g. kitchen equipment, preparing food and underneath these is where the relevant articles and videos sit)

What is the best way to present both video & articles in the same section? I know I could filter by media type which would help or have icons on the thumbnails to show what type of media it is.

Comment: Asking for 'any ideas or examples' makes it less likely to get good answers. Please consider to ask a little bit more specific.

Comment: can u show a demo if poss?

Comment: Can you also give us a layout example of the current route you've chosen so we have something to base the feedback on?

Comment: Please can you expand on what you mean by 'layout example of the current route chosen'?

Answer (score 1):

The way the BBC does this is to show thumbnails no matter what the content type is and then overlay an appropriate icon (such as the play button for video).

I personally find this easy to understand as I know what media type each link will contain before I go on it (It's useful for work to avoid the videos!).

[image]

What I would note from the screenshot is they have a title for video & audio, but I think you could safely mix them if you made the media type clear.

Answer (score 1):

Using thumbnails is a great idea, appended with a small icon that signifies the content type, as a play button for video and maybe something like a letter icon/text for an article. 
Thumbnails give a lot of life to your website and help to maintain a consistent site look